# Navigate to RootViewController from ModalViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have an app with 3 view controllers. A is the root, B is next and C is a modal view that appears / transitions when a button on B is clicked. What I want to do is sometimes move from C to A directly when a button on C is clicked (other times, the C->B transition should happen, which is ok). I've tried various options and incorporated info from different SO posts but in the end, stuck at the scenario where the direct transition from C to A happens but does show B momentarily.

Is there a way I can remove this momentary B appearance altogether. Also, I do need to have animations when the user goes from B to C or from C to B. It is the C to A transition that need not have an animation if there is a limitation there.

Hopefully you can chip in... have copied relevant code and further details below.

ViewControllerC.h:

```
@protocol ViewControllerCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didNavigateBackFromViewC:(ViewControllerC *)viewControllerC;

@end

@interface ViewControllerC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id < ViewControllerCDelegate > viewCDelegate;

@end
```

ViewControllerC.m:

```
- (IBAction)navigateToViewA:(id)sender
{
    [self.viewCDelegate didNavigateBackFromViewC:self];
}
```

For the B->C and C->B transitions, I've used a separate transitioning controller that is a delegate of ViewControllerB. Also, ViewControllerB is a delegate of UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate... I've not included those details for the sake of simplicity here but hopefully am able to convey the problem here about the C->A transition.

ViewControllerB.h:

```
@interface ViewControllerB () <ViewControllerCDelegate>

@end
```

ViewControllerB.m:

```
- (void)didNavigateBackFromViewC:(ViewControllerC *)viewControllerC
{
    __block ViewControllerB *me = self;
    [viewControllerC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [me.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Comment: B to C transition use push from navigationController. then, From C set popToRootViewController for move to A.

Comment: Thanks @VineeshTP ... unfortunately I need to have custom transitions between B and C, thus leveraging push from B to C doesn't work. I need to use present, which makes C a modal view controller, and thus can't run popToRootViewController from C to get to A directly....

Comment: add a delegate while transition from B to C then, trigger the delegate when dismiss the custom transition. In delegate method(From B)pop to viewController,A

Answer (score 0):

really interesting question @vikram17000.  First of all, you might want to try unwind segues, it seems that they can do what you want but I haven't tested that.  It appered you were going the programmatic route, and here's what i found.  I split (what I called) the 'back' and 'home' actions into two separate actions.  Here's my ViewControllerC code:

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)goHome:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate ViewControllerCWillGoHome:self];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ViewControllerB is the delegate that gets the -...WillGoHome, and it popsToRootVC **before** VC C dismisses.  This gets the behavior we want, C animates out and A is left - yay!  Unfortunately there's a catch -

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ViewControllerB: 0x7fc3c857ca80.

So is it possible? Yes.  Does the os like it? No it does not.  Hopefully this helps you get going though.

Comment: Thanks much @BoombaleOsby ... highly appreciate your feedback and the comments. As mentioned in my comment above too, somehow the view transitions get corrupted... I get the system warning about the unbalanced calls and if I don't keep any transition, it works fine but if I do, then there are strange black shadows that appear during the transition... Testing further by leveraging child view controllers... thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've created sample [project](https://github.com/bErKut/NavigationExample) for your question. 
There is protocol *GoBackProtocol* which contains method

```
-(void)controller:(UIViewController *)controller didPressBackButton:(UIButton *)button;
```

A and B controllers adopt GoBackProtocol. B controller implements -controller:didPressBackButton: method and decides based on *button* parameter what to do: hide presented controller with animation or hide it without animation and forward call to his delegate, which is controller A.

```
- (void)controller:(UIViewController *)controller didPressBackButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    ViewControllerC *modalController = (ViewControllerC *)controller;
    if (button == modalController.buttonB)
    {
        [controller.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (button == modalController.buttonA)
    {
        [controller.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self.delegate controller:self didPressBackButton:nil];
    }
}
```

Controller A implements -controller:didPressBackButton: as well and pops viewController B.

```
- (void)controller:(UIViewController *)controller didPressBackButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

All Together it makes desired effect.

Comment: Thanks much @curious for your detailed explanation and the same project. Much appreciate your taking out the time for the same... Unfortunately, the view transitions that I have get corrupted when I implement your code... if I do not use custom transitions, then your code works fine but the moment I introduce a transitioning delegate, the views get corrupted during the transition (not sure why...). I've found good results though whilst leveraging child view controllers - putting in some details below... thanks again nevertheless for your help!

Comment: @vikram17000 Can you provide actual code which you use for presenting and dismissing? Maybe I could help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Please forget all custom protocol solutions here. Apple says: 
[The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)

IMO you have at least two options here:

1) You could add the close button on C to public interface like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIButton *closeButton;
```

Set the target differently and use a combination of  *dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:* and *popToRootViewControllerAnimated:* as in your method *didNavigateBackFromViewC*

2) You could use *self.navigationController.presentingViewController* in C to get access to the non-modal viewcontrollers.

As non-official option you could set the viewcontrollers array on a UINavigationController instance directly. Then you will get a Push Animation from C to A.

Comment: Thanks much @Apoc for your comments.... much appreciated... I tried the 2nd option but not much success unfortunately. I was very optimistic about the non-official option about using a separate navigation controller instance for the A->C and C->A navigation, but then realized that B gets left out of the hierarchy and I do want to go to B also from A or C. Tried a bit with child view controllers - works so far... putting in some details below... but thanks again for your time and inputs!

Comment: You could do a normal _pushViewController:animated:_ to go from A to B. Use the non-offical transistion to go from C to A. And for A to C and B to C use _presentViewController_animated:completion:_.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully testing this out yet but results so far seem encouraging. Given that I wanted to be able to transition to B or C from A, and that B and C could navigate between each other, I've started playing around with making ViewControllerA as the container view controller for ViewControllerB and ViewControllerC. That allows me easy access to B / C from A, as well as the ability to transition between B and C seamlessly using custom transitions.